# What is the root username and password for CUPS 2.1.0

Tags: printing, user-account, cups

I don't remember creating one and I'm just trying to print in black and white.

Comment: Where do you need to enter username/password? Is there a dialog box of some kind?

Comment: Please consider selecting the below as a valid answer, it worked for me, I assume it did for you too?

Comment: @patrix: if you click on adming (localhost:631) it will provide a dialog box.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you don't need to enter a root username and password to use CUPS. The error is likely to be in /etc/cups/printers.conf You could check the authorization entries in your printers.conf

Even simpler though is that CUPS.org recommends just [using your normal admin username and password](http://www.cups.org/faq.php) when asked for authorization:

> Use the username and password for your computer.

You will need an account with admin privileges: most OS X computer owners have such an account, it's usually only in an lab or a company where you wouldn't have admin privileges.

I hope this works in your case, Esmeralda. If it doesn't please post some follow up information, such as your printers.conf file.